# Get invisible column real index in dataTables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables jQuery Plugin. In all tables, in `tfoot` I have an input to each `td`, so user can search in that.

I use this code:

```
    $("tfoot td").each(function (i) {
        $(this).on('change', 'select', function () {
            $('#paginacaoTabela').dataTable().fnFilter(this.value, i);
        });

        $(this).on('change', 'input', function () {
            $('#paginacaoTabela').dataTable().fnFilter(this.value, i);

        });
    });
```

But in some tables. I have a column selector that use `.fnSetColumnVis(iCol, bVis);`
After that, the column index change, and the filtering stop working.

My table HTML code is:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="paginacaoTabela">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Apresentante</th>
                    <th>Protocolo</th>
                    <th>Data apresentação</th>
                    <th>Número &nbsp;</th>
                    <th>Devedor &nbsp;</th>
                    <th>Documento</th>
                    <th>Endereço</th>
                    <th>Saldo &nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>Valor &nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>Praça pagamento</th>
                    <th>Data emissão</th>
                    <th>Data pagamento</th>
                    <th>Nosso número</th>
                    <th>Indicação</th>
                    <th>Situação</th>
                    <th class="not_toogle"><!-- devedores --></th>
                    <th class="not_toogle"><!-- id --></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar apresentante" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar protocolo" maxlength="10" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-small date-picker" placeholder="Pesquisar data apresentação" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar número" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar devedor" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar documento" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar endereço" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar saldo" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar valor" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar praça pagamento" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-small date-picker" placeholder="Pesquisar data emissão" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-small date-picker" placeholder="Pesquisar data pagamento" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar nosso número" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control input-xsmall" placeholder="Pesquisar indicação">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="0">Não</option>
                            <option value="1">Sim</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $this->listaSituacao(); ?></td>
                    <td><!-- devedores --></td>
                    <td><!-- id --></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

The DT code is:

```
var oTable = $('#paginacaoTabela').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": $(location).attr('href'),
         "aoColumns": [
             { "mData": "apresentante.nome" },
             { "mData": "protocolo" },
             { "mData": "dataProtocolo" },
             { "mData": "numero" },
             { "mData": "devedores.nome" },
             { "mData": "devedores.documento" },
             { "mData": "devedores.endereco" },
             { "mData": "saldo" },
             { "mData": "valor" },
             { "mData": "pracaPagamento" },
             { "mData": "dataEmissao" },
             { "mData": "dataPagamento" },
             { "mData": "nossoNumero" },
             { "mData": "indicacao" },
             { "mData": "situacao.nome" },
             { "mData": "devedores.id", 'bVisible': false },
             { "mData": "id" },
          ]
    }); 

    var cookieName = 'checkbox_consulta_';

    $(document).on('change', '#column_toggler input[type="checkbox"]', function() {

        var iCol = parseInt($(this).attr("data-column"));
        var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;

        bVis = (bVis ? false : true);

        $.cookie(cookieName + iCol, bVis);
        oTable.fnSetColumnVis(iCol, bVis);
    });

    $('#column_toggler input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {

        var iCol = parseInt($(this).attr("data-column"));

        if ($.cookie(cookieName + iCol) === 'false') {
            $(this).prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
        }

    });
```

If you want, you can see live here http://protesto21.com.br/titulo/consulta/ 
User manaca, password p21

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you filter through the otable?

```
.fnSetFilteringDelay(700) .append( 
                        '<tfoot><tr>' + 
                            '<td><input type="text" name="" placeholder="" class="input-block-level" /></td>' + 
                        '</tr>
                       </tfoot>');
$('#datatable-name tfoot input').keyup( function() {

    oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $('#datatable-name tfoot input').index(this) );
});
```

Comment: `$('#paginacaoTabela').dataTable()` gets tha DataTable instance. The problem is when I set a column invisible, the index change. I use ZF2 and Doctrine2. If I try search in column 3, and column 2 is invisible, datatables set sSearch_2 with my search string instead of sSearch_3